# Can I add a Suggests field to debian/control with a newer version recommendation for a package already in Build-Depends?

Tags: debian, package-management

My application, [ROXTerm](https://github.com/realh/roxterm), depends on vte-2.91 >= 0.52, but it performs a run-time check for a new feature in vte 0.64 which it can use to enhance UX by enabling kinetic scrolling for touch input devices, which otherwise would only be available by enabling a deprecated xorg driver (not available in Wayland).

The strict dependency on vte-2.91 >= 0.52 is managed by Build-Depends. Would it be appropriate to add `Suggests: vte-2.91 >= 0.64` to the binary package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, this doesn't make sense.

`>=0.64` is a strict superset of `>=0.52` dependency (this holds true for both mathematical comparision and dependency resolution).

The dependency you already have says: "use any version of `vte-2.91` that is newer than (or equal to) **0.52**".
This dependency can be satisfied by `vte2.19_0.52`, `vte2.19_0.63.9` and `vte2.19_0.77` (among others).

Now, the dependency resolver (`apt`) will pick the newest version that can satisfy it's dependencies (and that isn't downvoted by apt-pinning).

If your distribution release ships with `vte2.19_0.77` it will automatically pick that, but if it only comes with `vte2.19_0.52-9` it will pick that instead.

In short: if the distribution release lacks a `vte-2.91 >= 0.64` it *cannot* install that version, and if it comes with `vte-2.91 >= 0.64` it will pick that version anyways.
Adding a versioned `Suggests` doesn't change anything about this.

Comment: However, what if a user has stable as their preferred release, but has also enabled testing or unstable in sources.list for a few selected packages? Or a similar situation with LTS and latest release in Ubuntu? Wouldn't that make apt default to the stable version, but be able to install a newer version if a package prefers?

Comment: it doesn't matter, as the Dependencies/Suggests fields are orthogonal to apt-priorities and pinning.